# DLL starts with MZx in DOS header - what does it mean?

Tags: windows, header, dos

I found a program which uses a dll-file, which starts with MZx in the DOS header. I never saw this before in my life. I get ZERO results at google when i try to find explanations what this means. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What exactly does the MZx mean? Are there differences to a typical MZ header? Can i replace the dll with a "normal" one which starts with MZ or will it be not compatible?

Comment: It means nothing, it is not some kind of extension. You are seeing things that are not there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first two bytes are part of the signature, the rest is [the configuration](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.html) of the DOS program:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
     WORD e_magic; // MZ
     WORD e_cblp;  // Bytes on last page of file
     WORD e_cp;    // Pages in file
     ...
```

These "unusual" values are either required by the DOS program (unlikely in a .dll) or used as some kind of marker/storage for something. Either way, leave the values alone...